# Connecting Android causes Client Service Runtime Process to severely slow down PC

Tags: performance, cpu, android, reboot, csrss.exe

This issue has been bothering me for a long while, very weird and couldn't solve it.

When I connect my Nexus 4 Android to the PC, suddenly the Client Service Runtime Process CPU consumption jumps high and my PC slows down dramatically. Please see the screenshot.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rl8y.png]

The temporary solution was to restart the PC keeping Android connected, the PC would work fine at normal speed.

Cam someone please guide me how to fix this Client Services Runtime Process issue? It's really weird.

Comment: A quick fix to try would be setting the phone up with a static IP and block the IP in Windows firewall. Or a better thing to try would be putting the phone on a different subnet than the computer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, but could you please explain why do you think the issue has to do with networking ? what does Client Service Runtime Process (crss.exe) do ?

Comment: please provide a xperf trace of the CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD